# How to search for a file in Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I understand we can set Metadata for files we store in Firebase Storage.

Can we search/filter for files in Firebase Storage based on Metadata?

Comment: see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files

Answer (score 14):

You can do that from Google cloud storage browser: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser?project=**your-firebase-project-name**

There, you can search for any file name and do multiple actions on it.

Comment: This is the correct answer I feel and should be marked as such...

Answer (score 4):

Firebase SDKs now have an option to list files, though not to search them. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files

There is no way to list files, search for files or filter files within the Firebase Storage API.

There are some such features in the gcloud API, which can also be used on Firebase Storage.

Comment: Can you please provide link to the relevant gcloud API?

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't have more up votes.

Comment: Uhm... because it's actually outdated? :)   Firebase SDKs now have an option to list files (though not to search them). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files

Answer (score 1):

You can not search with current API but if it helps you can list files https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files