# Get all photo names from Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have stored users photos in firebase with unique names using NSUUID. I can delete the images with a reference to their exact names one after the other.
My question is, I had like to get all the photos names for bulk deletion but how?

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API in Firebase to list the files in Cloud Storage. So unless you already have a list of the names, you will have to either delete them from the Firebase console, or by using the Google Cloud Storage API.

See:

- [Delete folder with contents from Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214052/delete-folder-with-contents-from-firebase-storage)
- [FirebaseStorage: How to Delete Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749647/firebasestorage-how-to-delete-directory)
- [How to get an array with all pictures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-an-array-with-all-pictures)
- [How to search for a file in Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167989/how-to-search-for-a-file-in-firebase-storage)